# Bandwidth specification of Azure VMs

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machines, bandwidth

I am trying to set up Azure VMs in several regions with a guaranteed internet bandwidth of 2 Mbps. But I can't find the internet speed specification anywhere.

Comment: Did my answer help or solve your problem? Please upvote and/or accept my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [Virtual machine network bandwidth](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-machine-network-throughput)

> Azure offers a variety of VM sizes and types, each with a different
> mix of performance capabilities. One capability is network throughput
> (or bandwidth), measured in megabits per second (Mbps). Because
> virtual machines are hosted on shared hardware, the network capacity
> must be shared fairly among the virtual machines sharing the same
> hardware. Larger virtual machines are allocated relatively more
> bandwidth than smaller virtual machines.
>
> The network bandwidth allocated to each virtual machine is metered on
> egress (outbound) traffic from the virtual machine. All network
> traffic leaving the virtual machine is counted toward the allocated
> limit, regardless of destination. For example, if a virtual machine
> has a 1,000 Mbps limit, that limit applies whether the outbound
> traffic is destined for another virtual machine in the same virtual
> network, or outside of Azure.
>
> Ingress is not metered or limited directly. However, there are other
> factors, such as CPU and storage limits, which can impact a virtual
> machine’s ability to process incoming data.

[Expected network bandwidth for Av2 series VMs:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/av2-series)

- Standard_A1_v2: 250 Mbps
- Standard_A2_v2: 500 Mbps
- Standard_A4_v2: 1000 Mbps
- ...

**Further information**

[Virtual machine network bandwidth](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-machine-network-throughput)

[Sizes for virtual machines in Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes)

[Av2-series (see column Expected network bandwidth)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/av2-series)

Comment: Good point. A-series will be the ones to look at to ensure 2 Mbps.